# Spark on Bluemix : !pip install --user shapely == Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

```
!pip install --user shapely
```

results in

```
Collecting shapely
  Using cached Shapely-1.5.16.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Failed `CDLL(libgeos_c.so.1)`
    Failed `CDLL(libgeos_c.so)`
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/gpfs/global_fs01/sym_shared/YPProdSpark/user/s390-a2b719b24f799b-80b3d8dd92c1/notebook/tmp/pip-build-PYROZS/shapely/setup.py", line 38, in <module>
        from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
      File "shapely/_buildcfg.py", line 167, in <module>
        fallbacks=['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so'])
      File "shapely/_buildcfg.py", line 161, in load_dll
        libname, fallbacks or []))
    OSError: Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so']
```

How can I overcome this issue on Bluemix Spark service where I don't have admin permission to install libraries.

There are lots of similar questions, but none of them are about the Bluemix Spark service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
!wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.5.0.tar.bz2
!tar jxf geos-3.5.0.tar.bz2
!cd geos-3.5.0 && ./configure --prefix=$HOME/geos-bin && make && make install
!GEOS_CONFIG=$HOME/geos-bin/bin/geos-config pip install --user shapely
...
output omitted for brevity
...
Collecting shapely
  Using cached Shapely-1.5.16.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: shapely
  Running setup.py install for shapely ... [?25l- \ | / - \ | / - done
[?25hSuccessfully installed shapely-1.5.16
```